# Add Angular Material Ripple effect to Mat-Table on row click

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, material-design

I am using Angular Material v6. I want to add a Ripple effect anytime that a row in my `mat-table` is clicked.

**HTML:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="this.projectsList" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.title}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="this.displayColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: this.displayColumns"></tr>

</table>
```

**SCSS:**

```
table {
  width: 90vw;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mat-row:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

**Module Imports:**

```
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatSidenavModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatCheckboxModule
```

**Custom Theme:**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './palette.scss';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// **Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!**
@include mat-core();

// Define the default theme (same as the example above).
$light-primary-blue:    mat-palette($primary-blue);
$light-accent-purple:   mat-palette($accent-purple);
$light-theme:           mat-light-theme($light-primary-blue, $light-accent-purple);

// Include the default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($light-theme);

// Define an alternate dark theme.
$dark-primary: mat-palette($primary-blue);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($accent-purple);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent);

// Include the alternative theme styles inside of a block with a CSS class. You can make this
// CSS class whatever you want. In this example, any component inside of an element with
// `.dark` will be affected by this alternate dark theme instead of the default theme.
.dark {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

I can't find any documentation on adding a ripple effect to a table, but I have seen a couple Stackblitz instances that have ripple effects on row click. I tried copying what they were doing without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your td element as below.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="this.projectsList" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">
      <div class='mat-ripple-wrapper' matRipple>
        {{project.title}}
      </div> 
    </td>
  </ng-container>

</table>
```

Style

```
.mat-ripple-wrapper{
   position: relative;
}
```

The mat-ripple directive creates a div once the trigger element is clicked which makes it fall out of place if its placed on a row. Best I can get it to work in by wrapping the td data in a div and adding the directive on that div to contain the dynamically generated div.

Comment: this is not what the thread creator wanted. He wants the whole row to ripple. Your solution sets it on a column.